# PHP - Character Encoding Issue - Must be Missing Something

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

In my PHP page, product descriptions are showing up with the infamous Â£ issue.

Aha! I thought - I must remember to move the entire website over to UTF-8. So I:

- Specified in both the `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` and the `array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")` command. I'm migrating the website over to PDO - so still in a transitional process. The actual part of the website where the product description is saved and read both use the new PDO method.
- Specified `ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');` at the start of my header.php page.
- Specified `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` in the head tag of the HTML page. I verified that there were no caching issues by checking that it appears.
- Changed the collation of the products table to `utf8_general_ci`.

But the error still occurs. It even occurs on new products and when I edit the product to remove and re-add the pound sign. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Note that this doesn't happen when I type in `echo '£';` into the PHP directly, only when a string is being returned from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I was throwing `htmlentities()` onto the strings for security when I was echoing them to the browser. I should have thrown:

`htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");` to rectify this.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 more things

- set `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`
- make sure your file encoding is UTF-8 (eg: open file with notepad and save it as UTF-8 ENCODING)

Comment: Thanks. Setting the header didn't make a difference. I presume you mean the actual PHP page should be UTF-8 encoded. I'm using Linux and Aptana Studio, anyone know how I would check that?